# Htacces/Php - Too many redirects

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to make clean URLs at my website which i am working on local.

I am using WampServer.

Here is my `.htaccess` content

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) search.php?semt=$1 [NC,L]
```

Here is what i am doing at `search.php` file.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET["semt"]) || empty($_GET["semt"])){
    header("Location: index.php");}
else{
    $region = $_GET["semt"];
    include('database/config.php');
    include('includes/header.php');}
?>
```

When i am typing,

> localhost/project/search.php?semt=xxx
>   it is quite working.

When i am typing,

> localhost/project/search/xxx

it is not working. Browser giving this error.

[error screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezIFT.png)

This page isn’t working

localhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Final version of the link is that.

> localhost/project/search/index.php

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Is `xxx` what you're actually using, or does that stand for something else?

Comment: as an example. 
I tried to use that `RewriteRule ^esc/search/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) localhost/esc/search.php?semt=$1 [NC,L]`
it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see why this is happening from your final url. Change redirect to /index.php.